# Using scrapy to scrape multiple pages and multiple URLs

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, scrapy

I have previously done a small project on scraping a real estate website using BeautifulSoup, but it took a long time to scrape around 5,000 data points. I was thinking of learning multithread processing and implementing it with BS, but someone informed me that web-crawling with Scrapy might be faster and easier. Additionally, I have switched from using a Spyder to Pycharm as my IDE. It is still jarring experience but I am trying to get used to it.

I have gone over the documentation once, and followed some scraping examples using Scrapy, but I am still experiencing difficulties. I was planning to use my previously created BS scraping script as a base, and create a new Scrapy project to web-scrape real estate data. However, I don't know how and where I can start. Any and all help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**Desired Result:**
Scrape multiple pages from multiple URLs using Scrapy. Scrape multiple values by entering into the apartment listing links and getting data from each.

**Scrapy Script (so far):**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Import library
import scrapy


# Create Spider class
class UneguiApartmentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apartments'
    allowed_domains = ['www.unegui.mn']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/'
        ]
    # headers
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for listings in response.xpath("//div[@class='list-announcement']"):
            item = ApartmentsItem()
            item['name'] = listings.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['link'] = listings.xpath('href').extract()
        yield item
```

**BeautifulSoup Script:**

This script still has some issues I am trying to address such as scraping city and price. For example, for 4 bedroom apartments url (/4-r/) it creates an error or empty value because there are VIP listings

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import pandas as pd
import re
import csv

dt_today = datetime.today()
date_today = dt_today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
date_today2 = dt_today.strftime('%Y%m%d')
date_yesterday = (dt_today-relativedelta(day=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def main():
    page = 0
    name = []
    date = []
    address = []
    district = []
    city = []
    price = []
    area_sqm = []
    rooms = []
    floor = []
    commission_year = []
    building_floors = []
    garage = []
    balcony = []
    windows = []
    window_type = []
    floor_type = []
    door_type = []
    leasing = []
    description = []
    link = []
    
    for i in range (5,6):
        BASE = 'https://www.unegui.mn'
        URL = f'{BASE}/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/{i}-r/?page='
        COLUMNS=['Name','Date','Address','District','City','Price','Area_sqm','Rooms','Floor','Commission_year',
                 'Building_floors','Garage', 'Balcony','Windows','Window_type','Floor_type','door_type','Leasing','Description','Link']
        
        with requests.Session() as session:
            while True:
                (r := session.get(f'{URL}{page+1}')).raise_for_status()
                m = re.search('.*page=(\d+)$', r.url)
                if m and int(m.group(1)) == page:
                    break
                page += 1
                start = timer()
                print(f'Scraping {i} bedroom apartments page {page}')
                
                soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')
                for tag in soup.findAll('div', class_='list-announcement-block'):
                    _name = tag.find('a', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})
                    name.append(_name.get('content', 'N/A'))
                    if (_link := _name.get('href', None)):
                        link.append(f'{BASE}{_link}')
                        (_r := session.get(link[-1])).raise_for_status()
                        _spanlist = BS(_r.text, 'lxml').find_all('span', class_='value-chars')
                        floor_type.append(_spanlist[0].get_text().strip())
                        balcony.append(_spanlist[1].get_text().strip())
                        garage.append(_spanlist[2].get_text().strip())
                        window_type.append(_spanlist[3].get_text().strip())
                        door_type.append(_spanlist[4].get_text().strip())   
                        windows.append(_spanlist[5].get_text().strip())
                        
                        _alist = BS(_r.text, 'lxml').find_all('a', class_='value-chars')
                        commission_year.append(_alist[0].get_text().strip())
                        building_floors.append(_alist[1].get_text().strip())
                        area_sqm.append(_alist[2].get_text().strip())
                        floor.append(_alist[3].get_text().strip())
                        leasing.append(_alist[4].get_text().strip())
                        district.append(_alist[5].get_text().strip())
                        address.append(_alist[6].get_text().strip())
                        
                        rooms.append(tag.find('div', attrs={'announcement-block__breadcrumbs'}).get_text().split('»')[1].strip())
                        description.append(tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__description').get_text().strip())
                        date.append(tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__date').get_text().split(',')[0].strip())
                        city.append(tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__date').get_text().split(',')[1].strip())         
                        # if ( _price := tag.find('div', class_='announcement-block__price _premium')) is None:
                        #     _price = tag.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'price'})['content']
        
                        # price.append(_price)
                        end = timer()
                print(timedelta(seconds=end-start))
                
            df = pd.DataFrame(zip(name, date, address, district, city, 
                                  price, area_sqm, rooms, floor, commission_year,
                                  building_floors, garage, balcony, windows, window_type,
                                  floor_type, door_type, leasing, description, link), columns=COLUMNS)
            return(df)
    
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('Өнөөдөр', date_today)
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('Өчигдөр', date_yesterday)
        df['Area_sqm'] = df['Area_sqm'].replace('м²', '')
        df['Balcony'] = df['Balcony'].replace('тагттай', '')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = main()
    df.to_csv(f'{date_today2}HPD.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Scrapy is great though it's an entire framework you have to learn; maybe it would be easier to convert your program to async python if all you're looking for is speed improvements? Your current beautifulsoup scraper is being blocked a lot by requests and if you would redesign it with asyncio in mind you'd get a huge speed boost. See my blog on introduction async web scraping: https://scrapecrow.com/asynchronous-web-scraping.html

Answer (score 3):

this is an example of scraping  multiple URLs to the same website
for example
the website is amazon
the first URL for the baby category
the second for another category

```
import scrapy

class spiders(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "try"
    start_urls = ["https://www.amazon.sg/gp/bestsellers/baby/ref=zg_bs_nav_0",'https://www.amazon.sg/gp/browse.html?node=6537678051&ref_=nav_em__home_appliances_0_2_4_4']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('.mr-directory-item a::attr(href)').getall(): #loop for each href
            yield scrapy.Request(f'https://muckrack.com{url}', callback=self.parse_products,
                                 dont_filter=True)
    def parse_products(self, response):
#these are for another website 
        full_name = response.css('.mr-font-family-2.top-none::text').get()
        Media_outlet = response.css('.mr-person-job-item a::text').get()
       
        yield {'Full Name': full_name, 'Media outlet':Media_outlet,'URL': response.url}
```

if you want to do the different processes for each URL
you should use

````
import scrapy

class spiders(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "try"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('url1',callback=self.parse1)
        yield scrapy.Request('url2',callback=self.parse2)

    def parse1(self, response):
        for url in response.css('.mr-directory-item a::attr(href)').getall():#loop for each href
            yield scrapy.Request(f'https://muckrack.com{url}', callback=self.parse_products,
                                 dont_filter=True)
    def parse2(self, response):
        for url in response.css('.mr-directory-item a::attr(href)').getall():#loop for each href
            yield scrapy.Request(f'https://muckrack.com{url}', callback=self.parse_products,
                                 dont_filter=True)

    def parse_products(self, response):
        #these are for another website 
        full_name = response.css('.mr-font-family-2.top-none::text').get()
        Media_outlet = response.css('.mr-person-job-item a::text').get()
       #yield {'header':'data'}
        yield {'Full Name': full_name, 'Media outlet':Media_outlet,'URL': response.url}```
````

Comment: what will be the start_urls in this case??

Comment: @AdeenaLathiya you can define it and avoid using start_requests  or use start_requests it call start_requests and send it all urls

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is an asynchronous callback driven framework.
The `parse()` method is default callback to all `start_urls`. Now every callback can yield either:

- item - which will send it to pipelines if there are any and to output
- request - `scrapy.Request` object can be yielded to continue scraping.

So if you have multiple page scraper and you want to scrape all items your logic would look something like this:

```py
class MySpider(Spider):
   name = "pagination_spider"
   start_urls = ["first_page_url"]

   def parse(self, response):
       total_pages = ... # find total pages number in first page
       for page in range(1, total_pages):
           url = base_url + page  # form page url 
           yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)
       # also don't forget to parse first page
       yield from self.parse_page(self, response)

   
   def parse_page(self, response):
       """parse listing items from single pagination page"""
       item = {}  # parse page response for listing items
       yield item
```

Here the spider will request 1st page then schedule request for all remaining pages concurrently - meaning you can take full advantage of scrapy's speeds to get all listings.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How does looping work for Scrapy? If I put 5 urls as a list into the start_urls variable, would this still work? I think the main issue I am having is not only scraping all data from the page itself, but then scraping inside each href link on each page. Would using just a parse function work? Lastly, how do I set up the pipelines to scrape multiple urls/pages at the same time for speed. Sorry for the barrage of questions, and thank you in advance.